# How to set an alias which will automatically ssh to another server

Tags: linux, ssh, alias, xforwarding

I often use this command to connect to another server with x forwarding:

`[myuser@server1]$: ssh -Y 10.32.45.123`  (10.32.45.123 is server2)

```
myuser@10.32.45.123's password:

[$myuser@server2]:$
```

I need an alias which will ssh to server2 with -Y option, and also enter my password for me.

How do I do it?

Best Regards

Comment: Carry out `ssh-keygen -t rsa` accept defaults. Copy that file to using `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub myuser@10.32.45.123`then you can use `ssh -Y 'myuser@10.32.45.123'`. Use [this](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) if you need more help. (Although its from Debian, it applies to all Linux flavours). Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, while aliases are good with only a few servers, ssh config file is a bit better for a larger environment, and a few other neat tricks in the comments on this page: http://www.howtogeek.com/75007/stupid-geek-tricks-use-your-ssh-config-file-to-create-aliases-for-hosts/